# How do I add external links in Shopify Schema?

Tags: shopify

I've tried using "type": "url:". and apparently that only works for collections. I want to make a dynamic external link. I tried text input. Why is this one task not easy to do?

````
 <a class="section-tiktok__card" href="{{block.settings.url}}">
            <img src="{{ 'tik-play-btn.svg' | asset_url }}" alt="play video">
        </a> 


{% schema %}
    {
    "name": "TikTok Feed",
    "presets": [{
        "name": "TikTok Section"
    }],

    "blocks": [{
        "type": "html",
        "limit": 5,
        "name": "TikTok and Instagram Feed",
        "settings": [
            {
                "type": "image_picker",
                "id": "tiktok_bg",
                "label": "Image Background"
            },
            {
                "type": "url",
                "id": "tiktok_url",
                "label": "Tiktok or Instagram URL"
            }
        ]
    }]
}


{% endschema %}```
````

Comment: Why are you under the impression that URL is limited to collections only? That isn't the case. Are you seeing an error when you attempt that?

Comment: No URL shows up in the output. Is this the proper scope?      block.settings.url

Comment: Is that the entirety of the file? Is it in the sections folder?

Comment: No, block settings are accessed using id not with type so use `block.settings.tiktok_url` instead of `block.settings.url `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to get a setting from a block but you haven't accessed your section blocks or assigned anything to `block`. Furthermore, your setting is named `tiktok_url` while you're using `url` to display it.

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
    <a class="section-tiktok__card" href="{{ block.settings.tiktok_url }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
        <img src="{{ 'tik-play-btn.svg' | asset_url }}" alt="play video">
    </a> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I actually tried the id but kept adding .url to the tag. Then I read a post on stackoverflow that URL was only used for collections. But your solution works perfectly and thanks for your timely response.